# I have trouble playing youtube videos on Firefox using Gnash

Tags: firefox, gnash

I have been using 12.04 since it came out(I had to experiment to get YT work at all) and I have kept it up-to-date. After the latest updates, Firefox will play YT videos if I don't sign in, but will not play them if I do. I don't use Flashplayer, but Gnash SWF viewer and Gstreamer, and the window says "Powered by Youtube". If the video is HTML5, I get sound but not videos. Chrome works, but crashes a lot. Neither of them will load the comments on the video. Anyone have an idea of what's up?

Answer (score 0):

Gnash flash support for Youtube is very limited at best. I can't watch videos or see them with poor quality in my system. I would remove Gnash and use the [HTML5 solution](http://youtube.com/html5) instead of flash based.